# Flash 10 3D making text blur

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, 3d, matrix

I got a Sprite that I'm rotating with rotationX & rotationY. This converts the clip to 3d object. Which makes texts in it blurred.

When I'm rotating this clip back to rotationX=0 and rotationY=0, I'm setting:
this.transformation.matrix3D = null;
Which makes the texts crisp.

BUT, when I'm adding another clip to this sprite, that has z=400 (or any z). The texts just won't get crisp, the other clips in my sprite that I have been rotated seems to still be 3d even if i set:
this.transformation.matrix3D = null;

I've even tried to removeChild on the clip with z=400 when rotation is 0. And also tried setting matrix3D = null on that clip. But that doesn't help. Any one having any ideas how to "get rid" of the 3d of the clip with z=400? Or do I have to move that clip with z away from the clip I'm rotating (other things will mess up =)?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understood your question is talked in this post of Keith Peters, you might want to take a look as he explains it really well:

http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=2391

"Basically, if you have a series of three or more nested objects, and apply 3D transformations to TWO of them, any clips nested between those two will become 3D objects (i.e. have a matrix3D property)."

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Don't think the problem (even if was nice to know) mentioned in the blog is what I was handling with.

I solved this by simply moving the clip with z=400 out of the clip I was rotating. This caused some other "workarounds" but atleast it maked the text perfectly readable =)

Answer (score 0):

Set the transformation matrix to null...

```
myDisplayObject.transform.matrix3D = null;
```